# Issues using isEqualToString: iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, unrecognized-selector

I'm trying to take an array that came from a plist, and use that strings to know if they  already exists in the context.

But this error is happening

> reason: '-[__NSCFArray isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

here is the code..

```
- (NSArray*)loadPlist
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AlreadyDownloaded" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSArray *plistArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[dict allValues]];

    return plistArray;
}


-(void)writeToList:(NSArray *)text
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AlreadyDownloaded" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *copy = [self loadPlist];
    NSMutableArray *list = [copy mutableCopy];



    [list addObjectsFromArray:text];

    NSArray *array  = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"ObjectsIDS", nil];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    for(NSString *ob in list)
    {

        [dict setValue:ob forKey:@"ObjectsIDS"];

    }
    [dict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

}

-(bool)compareIDS:(NSString *)text
{
    NSArray *copy = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[self loadPlist]];
    NSMutableArray *list = [copy mutableCopy];
    NSMutableString *st = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];


    for(NSString *ob in copy)
    {

        if([ob isEqualToString:text])
            return YES;


    }
    return NO;
}
```

Thank you guys!

Best Regards.

Comment: Read the error. It's clear that `ob` is actually an `NSArray` and not an `NSString`. That means that the objects from `loadPlist` are not what you think they are.

Comment: Check the structure of plist.

Comment: Add an `NSLog(@"%@",plistArray);` at the end of the `loadPlist` method to see what you have in `plistArray`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use

[NSArray indexOfObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObject:) Method:

```
return [copy indexOfObject:text] != NSNotFound
```

or

```
for(int i = 0; i < copy.count; i++) {
     if([(NSString *) [copy objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:text]) return YES; 
}
return NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

From the crash log we doubt the NSString *ob is an array, rather then a NSString, you'd better set a  break point at for(NSString *ob in copy), the po the the object ob.

Comment: how do i copy all values from a certain key in the NsDictionary?